# Ajax code not working as intended on first run

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax script on a PHP page which is to run a php script on clicking a button.

The code is as follows:

```
    <script>
$('#signup-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
    $.ajax({
    url: 'insertfromsession.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#form-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
             $('#form-container').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
        });

        document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").value="Thanks!";
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
    });
});
```

When I first open the web page the script isn't run, but if i click back and repeat the process the script executes without an issue.  Does anyone know what is causing the issue?

Insert.php which runs this code is here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/submit.js"></script>
        <!-- /.website title -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <!-- CSS Files -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="fonts/icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
           body { background: white !important; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
        </style>
        <!-- Colors -->
        <link href="css/css-index.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- <link href="css/css-index-green.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->
        <!-- <link href="css/css-index-purple.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->
        <!-- <link href="css/css-index-red.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->
        <!-- <link href="css/css-index-orange.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->
        <!-- <link href="css/css-index-yellow.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> -->

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic" />
    </head>

        <div id="top"></div>
        <div class="fullscreen landing parallax" style="background-image:url('images/fireworks.jpg');" data-img-width="2000" data-img-height="1333" data-diff="100">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <!-- /.logo -->
                            <!-- /.main title -->
                            <h2 class="wow fadeInLeft">Thank you for submitting your details</h2>
                            <h2 class="wow bounce infinite">While you are here, why not apply for one of other fantastic products?</h2>


                                <?php
                                session_start();

                                include ("dbconnect.php");

                                // prepare and bind
                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wills (forename,surname,postcode,telno,email,ipaddress,capturedate,url,user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                                $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $forename, $surname, $postcode, $telno, $email, $ipaddress, $capturedate, $url, $user);

                                $forename         = $_POST["forename"];
                                $surname          = $_POST["surname"];
                                $postcode         = $_POST["postcode"];
                                $telno            = $_POST["telno"];
                                $email            = $_POST["email"];
                                $ipaddress        = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                                $capturedate      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                                $url              ="www.test.com";
                                $user             ="testuser";

                                $_SESSION["forename"] = $forename;
                                $_SESSION["surname"] = $surname;
                                $_SESSION["postcode"] = $postcode;
                                $_SESSION["telno"] = $telno;
                                $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                                $_SESSION["ipaddress"] = $ipaddress;
                                $_SESSION["capturedate"] = $capturedate;
                                $_SESSION["url"] = $url;
                                $_SESSION["user"] = $user;

                                echo "<br>"."Forename: ".$forename."<br>";
                                echo "Surname: ".$surname."<br>";
                                echo "Telno: ".$telno."<br>";
                                echo "Email: ".$email."<br>";
                                echo "IP Address: ".$ipaddress."<br>";
                                echo "Session User: ".$_SESSION["user"]."<br>";

                                if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                                    echo $stmt->error;
                                } else {

                                }

                                $stmt->close();
                                $conn->close();
                                ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>




                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center"><a href="index.html">Back to Main Page</a></div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <!-- /.product 1 -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6 feat-list">
                                    <i class="pe-7s-phone pe-5x pe-va wow fadeInUp"></i>
                                    <div class="inner">
                                        <h4>Grab a Mobile SIM</h4>
                                           <p>With a SIM only contract, you get the all the benefits of an ongoing contract, without the additional high cost of a handset.
                                           Short-term SIM only contracts give you freedom and flexibility. All the networks offer them from as little as 30 days, and you can then keep them rolling month-by-month
                                        </p>
                                            <form method="post" id="signup-form" autocomplete="off">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" id="submitBtn" value="Apply for Mobile Sim?">
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                                   <!-- /.product 2 -->
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 feat-list">
                                        <i class="pe-7s-like2 pe-5x pe-va wow fadeInUp"></i>
                                        <div class="inner">
                                        <h4>Debt Plan</h4>
                                            <p>Do you have more than &pound5,000 worth of debt?<br>
                                            Do you need help to reduce the monthly payments?<br>
                                            If so, find out if you qualify to write off up to 80% of your debt here</p>
                                        <form method="post" id="signup-formdebt" autocomplete="off">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" id="submitBtndebt" value="Get help now">
                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>

        <!-- /.footer -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <!-- /.social links -->
                    <div class="social text-center">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="wow fadeInUp" href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="wow fadeInUp" href="https://www.facebook.com/" data-wow-delay="0.2s"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="scrollToTop"><i class="pe-7s-up-arrow pe-va"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- /.javascript files -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                                    new WOW().init();
        </script>
    </body>
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#signup-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
        $.ajax({
        url: 'insertfromsession.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#form-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                 $('#form-container').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            });

            document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submitBtn").value="Thanks!";
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
        });
    });
});
    </script>

        <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log( "ready!" );
                    $('#signup-formdebt').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'insertfromsessiondebt.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $(this).serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
                            dataType: 'html'
                        })
                        .done(function(data){
                            $('#form-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                                 $('#form-container').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                            });

                            document.getElementById('submitBtndebt').disabled = true;
                            document.getElementById("submitBtndebt").value="Thanks!";
                        })
                        .fail(function(){
                            alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
                        });
                    });

        });

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like the dom may not be ready when you run bind to the form. You need to bind to the form when the document is ready. `$(document).ready(function() { // bind to form on submit })`

Comment: I'm very new to this, so to clarify I just need to put $(document).ready(function() { **insert my script here**}) in order to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the issue and it has nothing at all to do with the AJAX.  It actually appears to be an issue with the session variables.  I moved the session variables on the insert.php right to the top before anything else and this makes it work as intended.

Thanks for your efforts guys

Answer (score -1):

You should use a `document.ready` function.  Here is a link to the jQuery version documentation : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I'm very new to this, so to clarify I just need to put $(document).ready(function() { insert my script here}) in order to fix the issue?

Comment: Exactly, all the javascript code inside will be executed when all your dom's elements are loaded.

Comment: updated the script but theres not change to the behavoir

Comment: Ive added the insert.php to the initial post - thanks

Comment: There's no reason to put code that is at the bottom of the page inside a document ready function.

Comment: @KevinB "A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." (jQuery doc), just an other script  loaded slowly and your page doesn't work if it was needed... In many case there's no need but it's a good practice and prevents bugs.

Comment: maybe so, but t is irrelevant to this question as an answer.

Comment: I thought it was the problem.

Comment: To be fair, @Pierre-AdrienMaison wasn't aware it was at the bottom of my page.  I added the insert.php in response to him asking for more info.  Can any of you see anything else which could be causing the issue?